# FileMaker Pro 11: import data from customer copy

Tags: export, import, filemaker

I'm starting to make some changes to a FileMaker Pro 11 database for a customer. It's my first job on a FileMaker db. 
I need to work on the copy I got and after the work is completed, I'll have to import the data from the working (customer's) copy replacing the data in the new version of the database. 
I'm trying to use the FileMaker "Import Records -> File" menu. So I assumed I could import from data from the working copy. But I only get the option to:

1. Add New Records (that appends the imported records as new)
2. Update existing records (but this, if I understood correctly would not delete records that have been deleted in the working copy, but only update the existing ones)
3. Update matching records

None of this option seems to actually replace the data in the target database.

Is there any other option that I can't find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the new copy, delete all records.

Import all records from current database.

I don't recall if there's any way to make this method retain the creation and modification dates for the old records. If, as I vaguely recall, you have to provide a storage field to do anything useful with those dates, it may be possible to import them (if you are using them at all.)